# Is it possible to set Windows to downmix all 5.1 surround audio to stereo on driver level?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, surround-sound, stereo

I have about 2000 media files that I run through Plex on my laptop, which has stereo speakers. The problem is most of these files have the audio track distributed through 6 surround channels, which results in very low playback volume.

I know I could use ffmpeg with a few different available algorithms to reencode those files, but that would be an ever bigger problem, as my library is constantly being expanded and enhanced.

Is there any way to configure Windows 10's audio drivers to do this downmixing on a lower level?

I'll leave a Speccy snapshot of my system [here](http://speccy.piriform.com/results/x85K2i6qMG8qqEfffdSWycn) as it may help.

Comment: 5.1->Stereo is not the issue. There is so little in the rears & sub compared to the rest that it ought to average as 'stereo with the centre a bit quiet, sometimes' ie, perfectly comprehensible with slightly wider perception than a well-tempered 5.1..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not that well versed in audio therms, so I didn't quite understand your words. What I can say is that my media files are Scene releases, which have very tight audio and video standards, and that I don't face similar issues with other sources, such as games, youtube videos or similar sourced stereo files in my library.

Comment: I don't know what a 'scene release' is.

Comment: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Standard_(warez)

Comment: if it's a pirated copy, then blame the people who transcoded it from the original. We cannot help you with "warez".

Comment: It's not a transcode, it's the original, which is 5.1. And as I said, I don't need help with the files, I know how to use ffmpeg to "fix" them, but I want to adapt my system to downmix 5.1 to stereo.

Comment: @FabioFreitas did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Frans not really, I ended up writing a script to create a new downmixed stream and place it as the first audio stream while conserving the original as the second stream. You can find it here: https://github.com/fabiorzfreitas/Downmixer